# Angular. @Input set get null parameters but in antoher function values are initialized

Tags: angular, input

parent component does this :

```
 protected loadSelectedSource(source: TableSource) {
if (isPresent(source)) {
  this.tableWidgetSettingsService.getTableColumns(source).subscribe((tableColumns) => {
    this.tableColumns = tableColumns;
    this.availableObjectColumnIdentifiers = this.mapColumnsToSortableItems(tableColumns);
    if (this.selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers.length === 0) {
      this.availableObjectColumnIdentifiers.forEach((column) => {
        if (column.position > 0) {
          if (!this.isDuplicateSelectedColumn(column)) {
            this.selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers.push(column);
            if (!isPresent(this.lastInit)) {
              this.formGroupOptions.tableColumns.setErrors(null);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers = this.sortByPosition(
        this.selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers,
      );
    }
  });
}
```

}

child component receives :

```
<multi-sortable-selection
            [formatter]="formatColumn"
            [availableItems]="availableObjectColumnIdentifiers"
            (selectedItemsChange)="selectColumns($event, isObjectColumns)"
            [selectedItems]="selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers"
```

my child component ts:

```
@Input() set selectedItems(items: SortableItem[]) {
    this._selectedItems = this.sortByPosition(items);
  }
```

if i just write @Input selectedItems ... i get some values .
but with the @Input() set selectedItems(items) ... items is always null, even with breakpoints, it never gets values.

But if, an another set :

```
set availableItems(items) {
        this._availableItems = items;
        this.availableItemsDisplayed = this.sortByFormat(this._availableItems.filter((item) => !isPresent(this._selectedItems.find((item2) => item2.key === item.key))));
        this._selectedItems = this.sortByPosition(this._selectedItems);
    }
```

this.selectedItems get the right values !!

my questions :

- why my @Input set ... doesn't cacth values while my @Input does.
- why this._selectedItems get initialized whithout passing in set.

thanks !

- breakpoints
- html is good, i pass the right value

Comment: You have a race condition. Do you know which gets set first? You'd rather change them to normal fields and use ngOnChanges to catch all changes at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks. selectedItems is set first then availableItems.
i tried this : 
```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.availableItems) {
      this.availableItemsDisplayed = this.sortByFormat(
        this.availableItems.filter(
          (item) => !isPresent(this.selectedItems.find((item2) => item2.key === item.key)),
        ),
      );
    }
    if (changes.selectedItems) {
      this.selectedItems = this.sortByPosition(this.selectedItems);
    }
  }   
```
    but selectitem is still null but my values are well displayed

Comment: It was a rhetorical question where the answer is actually that you cannot know, because it depends on the behavior of the angular compiler. In changes you should check `if (changes.availableItems && changes.selectedItems)` But if both references are set and you receive null in the changes, than clearly the `selectedItems` is null and it might be updated very soon after that, but not soon enough. Perhaps you could share some of the component code of the html-page to so we can analyse the problem. Right now, there is not enough to help you.

Comment: haha, sorry, too first degree. 
in any case, I think my component was wrong. I processed my data in the parent component. As a result, the @Input() selectedItems displays what I want. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you've figured it out. If it is relevant, you can improve your question with the necessary details and post the answer to it too. If not, you can also delete your question.

Comment: i've added parent componet ts for more information. 
i've found a workaround as indicated in my previous answer but it's not satisfactory. Trying to work with locales variables and then set the values of selectedObjectColumnIdentifiers and availableObjectColumnIdentifiers doesn't change anything. Child component still receives empty array in @Input() set ... but values are well displayed ...